# I can-t use Alt Gr key to type symbols, and also some keys do what they're not supposed

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, windows

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and I need help configuring my keyboard so it works like Windows. Like I need to be able to login into stuff and would like to do it without copying and pasting an at symbol like I've been doing all day.

Comment: Sounds like you have the wrong language layout loaded.

Comment: But which one should I load?

Comment: What country are you from? Which layout is loaded in Windows?

Comment: I-m from Portugal, but my OS is in English, so I chose that one.

Comment: OS =  English means that all menus are in English, your keyboard hardware will most likely be set up according to Portuguese standards. So try the Portuguese layouts maybe? BTW: @ is at shift+2 in English keyboards

Comment: If you want some points or whatever put in in the answers I'll pick it.

Comment: Better not have solved problems as open questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard layouts need to match the hardware not the software / OS language.

Just change the layout to your country's specifications in settings -> keyboard -> layouts.

US-English keyboard has the @-symbol at shift+2, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards

Answer (score 1):

In my case I found out that I had previously used `gnome-tweaks` to set the Right Alt / Alt Gr key as the "Compose Key" and it prevented me from using that key in keyboard layouts that use Alt Gr.

I just had to go back into gnome-tweaks, Keyboard & Mouse and set "Compose Key" to "Disabled".